# codeigniter email variable unable to be displayed

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been trying to solve a simple bug for the past few hours but failed.

I am not sure why but a variable containing an email address when stored into session userdata could not be displayed, when var_dump(), it return bool(false).
The problem is when i `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());` , all the info is there intact including the email address. Only when I `var_dump($this->session->userdata('emailadd'));` it returns bool(false).

Here is my code:
Inside my summary controller

```
$data = array(
     'case' => $case,
     'cusname'=> $this->input->post('cusname'),
     'emailadd '=> $this->input->post('emailadd'),
     'contact'=> $this->input->post('contact')
);
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
redirect('summary/view');
```

So summary/view controller loads up a view-v.php view file.
The view-v.php view file displays out all the data stored in the session.

```
<html>
<head><title>View</title>
<body>
Name:<?php echo $this->session->userdata('cusname'); ?>
Email:<?php echo $this->session->userdata('emailadd'); ?>
Case:<?php echo $this->session->userdata('case'); ?>
Contact:<?php echo $this->session->userdata('contact'); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Everything else displayed normally except email address.

I am not sure why, according to logic it should all work fine.
P/S Session library is set to autoload in config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have left space after `emailadd`

```
'emailadd '=> $this->input->post('emailadd'),
         ^^
        space
```